# AVD Stuck in Landscape

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-virtual-device

I'm new here. Have run in problem regarding the above.
I have no problems rotating the orientation of the AVD.
But, my home screen, apps and all are stuck in landscape mode.

screenshot in the links below (i can't post images yet)

[landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVHKK.png)
[portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdq7S.png)

Comment: May be you should mention the platform you are developing on? It might help in this case.

Comment: I tried it with my emulator using CTRL + F12. i see no such problems. I am using 4.1.2.

Comment: i'm not really developing yet...just learning android as i go along.
i'm using win 8.

from the screenshots, i managed to use the ctrl+F11 or ctrl+F12 to change the rotation. it happens only to my virtual device which i set for galaxy s3. if i launch the nexus 7 avd. there's no problem.

i'll try to see what else did i miss while setting up the avd. else, i would reconfig a new avd for the S3.

Comment: silly me...i had copied a default settings over...to this S3 configuration.

it is because it was set as:
4.8" WXGA (1280 x 720:xhdpi)

should be:
4.8" WXGA (720 x 1280:xhdpi)